# Is there a chat group where I can thank all the moderators and members of the Japanese Language SE?

Tags: support

First off, I'd like to thank everyone who has been very patient in answering all the questions I have posted on the main site. This site has always been my go-to resource whenever I'm at loss in my Japanese studies (which happens most of the time given the level I'm in). Self-studying Japanese is difficult, being confined in my house for 3 months now has been difficult especially that I cannot go to the language exchange meetups. But this site made me feel a sense of community that I can always come to. Sure, learning Japanese is difficult, but precisely because it's difficult, I have learned to rely more on others throughout my language journey, and this site has been an avenue for that. Thank you!

Secondly, I don't know where I can post about things like this. I've been thinking of using the chat, but I'm not very familiar with it, and I'm afraid that I would just clutter the chat box if I post something like this there. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you misunderstand. The Stacks are kept alive by community contribution, which involves **asking questions**. Therefore, by asking questions, you've already done your bit and indirectly expressed gratitude. Thank *you* for your contributions!

Answer (score 1):

Your "question" is not quite clear but I think it's perfectly fine to use the website's [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language). It's a pretty laid back place and as long as you don't make it a nuisance almost any topic related to the Japanese language is okay.

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought of messaging them in private. I heard that there's a feature like that but I'm not sure.